# How to place Multiple MapViews v1 inside a ViewFlipper

Tags: android, google-maps, slideshow, viewflipper, mapactivity

**Objective**- I want to show **slide shows of different Map Activities** which show data according to database, using view flipper(or something similar).

**Issues:**

1. View Flipper can't be added to an Activity that is not a MapActivity if flipper contains a mapview.
2. View Flipper does not allows adding multiple mapviews as one MapActivity can have only one map view.

**What I wish to implement**

1. Want to show slide show of multiple  MapActivities which show markers,route etc based on database data.
2. Want to refresh these MapActivities also new data is fetched periodically and database is updated.

I'am unable to find a solution to my problem. I have gone through the following links but they provided no relevant solution:

[How can i Implement SlideShow in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8767795/how-can-i-implement-slideshow-in-android)

[Can a MapView be placed inside a ViewFlipper somehow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7247258/can-a-mapview-be-placed-inside-a-viewflipper-somehow)

Please help and suggest what is the best approach for this problem.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you considered using Google Maps Android API v2 instead?

Comment: no i need to use api v1 only cause I want app to be compatible with ginger bread also

Comment: V2 is compatible with gingerbread. Anyway just in case you are starting the project, you can't have v1 to work at all. Map won't load.

Comment: I dont understand why the question is downvoted .Pls add a comment if you are down voting !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not find standard solution to my problem as view flipper could not be used.**I did the following to implement mapview slide show**. Its more of a hack than a proper solution but I had no choice.

1. In a while loop, I kept re-rendering the same map view in the async map task.

2.After  1st map is loaded I called thread.sleep(10000).

3.I cleared the mapview of all routes and markers.

4.I re rendered the 2nd map view.

5.And the steps were repeated continuously.

```
@Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        final Drawable marker_inBetween;

        marker_inBetween = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.blue_pin);
        marker_inBetween.setBounds(0, 0,
                marker_inBetween.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                marker_inBetween.getIntrinsicHeight());

        helper = new DbHelper(getApplicationContext());
                    // show slide show
            while (true) {
        ArrayList<String> IdList =showAllPeopleOnMap();


                util.haveASleep(slideShowInterval);

                showEachPersonRouteOnMap(IdList);
                resetVariables();//resets lists,routes,removes markers etc
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Thanks.